# Compare rotated images in java

Tags: java, junit, comparison, bufferedimage

I have a picture and a rotated picture to compare.

```
    if (this.img.getHeight() == img1.getWidth() && this.img.getWidth() == img1.getHeight()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.img.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.img.getHeight(); j++) {
                assertEquals(this.img.getRGB(i, j), img1.getRGB(this.img.getWidth() - j, i));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the loop I use, but somehow it doesn't work.

The picture is rotated by 90° clockwise.

`this.img` is the original picture, `img1` is the rotated picture. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there any error?

Comment: No, It just tells me the rgb isn't the same, but I know its the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you need...

```
img1.getRGB(this.img1.getWidth() - j, i));
```

instead of

```
img1.getRGB(this.img.getWidth() - j, i));
```

...since you want to go from the width of the rotated image to the left, instead of the width of the original image (since that would have become the height and thus would not appear on any x-axis calculation).